# Generate random number for 5min

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to create a database that basically generates a random 6digit number for 5min (it can expire)and the user to be able to "send" to the database that number if it was within the time limit it would get the users name,email and date when he send it.I am confused though how am i supposed to do that?
In my current code i get the list of all registered users.
Whats the best way to do that should i create a new database that stores that number and the users should i just add that number into my current database?

```
package com.example.prologue.activities;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.prologue.R;
import com.example.prologue.adapters.UsersRecyclerAdapter;
import com.example.prologue.model.User;
import com.example.prologue.sql.DatabaseHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UsersListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppCompatActivity activity = UsersListActivity.this;
    private AppCompatTextView textViewName;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewUsers;
    private List<User> listUsers;
    private UsersRecyclerAdapter usersRecyclerAdapter;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_list);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        initViews();
        initObjects();

    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize views
     */
    private void initViews() {
        textViewName = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        recyclerViewUsers = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewUsers);
    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize objects to be used
     */
    private void initObjects() {
        listUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        usersRecyclerAdapter = new UsersRecyclerAdapter(listUsers);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerViewUsers.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewUsers.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerViewUsers.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewUsers.setAdapter(usersRecyclerAdapter);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);

        String emailFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("EMAIL");
        textViewName.setText(emailFromIntent);

        getDataFromSQLite();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to fetch all user records from SQLite
     */
    private void getDataFromSQLite() {
        // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation not blocks the UI Thread.
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                listUsers.clear();
                listUsers.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllUser());

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                usersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user `handler` to repeat a task with a `delay`

```
private int counter = 0; // global var
private int random = 0; // global var

final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.post(r);

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //generate random number and do you work
        random = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
        counter++;
        // call Runnable again after 1 sec if counter <= 3000 (50 min)
        if (counter <= 3000){ // 3000 = 50min
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1000 = 1 sec
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: it did thanks a lot made it a lot clearer on what im supposed to do thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try below best solution for your question

It's generate random number for 5 min.

```
Timer timer=new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 > 300 * 1000) {
            cancel();
        } else {
            int random = new Random().nextInt(51) + 20; // [0, 50] + 20 => [20, 70]
        }
    }
},1000,1000);
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.